# Feature linked annotation not added when new features are drawn

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, annotation

I created feature linked annotation for a line feature class. Both the feature and the annotation are feature classes stored within the same feature dataset on an SQL Server Geodatabase.

The initial labeling made use of a simple SQL query which may or may not be relevant. The annotation was created successfully but I'm having a hard time maintaining it due to the following:

- When I create a new feature that matches the filtering requirements of my feature linked annotation, the annotation is not created automatically.  Instead I have to select the feature and then click Selection > Annotate selected features.  It's my understanding from reading through ESRI's help that the annotation should be created automatically for any newly added features.  These new features DO match the sql query I initially made use of.

I also posted [Dragging feature- linked annotation results in strange snapping and rotation behavior](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216109) which is a similar but different question here as well.  They are not duplicates.

Comment: A coworker found the answer to my question at this link:  https://geonet.esri.com/thread/52888

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have ran into this problem before and this seemed to work for me.

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/52888

> The SQL Query is exactly what's stopping the annotation from getting
>   created.
>
> The composite relationship class allows for new annotation to get
>   created as soon as a new feature in the related feature class is
>   created.  This process only happens at the exact moment that the new
>   feature is committed to the database (before you ever modify attribute
>   information).  When a SQL Query is being used to limit the annotation
>   that is seen in a particular anno class, the value(s) which match the
>   SQL query must be present at the time the feature is created for the
>   related anno to get created as well.  In your case, they're not.

Comment: please avoid posting link-only answers.  Links often go stale and we would like to maintain good quality answers.  Could you please edit your question to show the parts of the page you linked to that will help the OP?