# Dragging feature- linked annotation results in strange snapping and rotation behavior

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, annotation

I created feature linked annotation for a line feature class. Both the feature and the annotation are feature classes stored within the same feature dataset on an SQL Server Geodatabase.

The initial labeling made use of a simple SQL query which may or may not be relevant. The annotation was created successfully but I'm having a hard time maintaining it due to the following:

- When dragging these annotation boxes to fine tune my print product, I use the Edit annotation tool. I've attempted this in both data and layout view (with a focused data frame). When stretching this bubble style annotation it is automatically rotated in a variety of directions and appears to snap to some unknown grid even though all snapping is turned off.  It makes placing annotation impossible.

I posted [Feature linked annotation not added when new features are drawn](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216107) which is a related but different question here today. These are not duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

If you have other layers turned on, the annotations will try to snap to layers even if you don't have them selectable. Make sure all your layers are turned off except for the one you want to edit when trying to move or edit annotations.